# JDBC + Java Query execution error

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm getting this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'auyu' in 'where clause'
```

My Query and method in my database facade class.

```
db.save("delete from users where name = auyu");

public static void save(String sql) throws Exception {
        new DBFacade().connect();
        synchronized (c) {
            c.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to Jon Skeet's answer.  Expanding and perhaps going OT, but it's best to parameterize these things and ensure escaping so that you aren't susceptible to SQL-injection attacks.  E.g.:

```
public static void deleteUser(userName)
throws Exception
{
    PreparedStatement ps;

    new DBFacade().connect();
    // (Assuming 'c' is a connection that's in scope somehow)
    synchronized (c) {
        // (You'd want to cache the prepared statement in an appropriate
        // way related to how you're handling connections and pooling)
        ps = c.prepareStatement("delete from users where name = ?");
        ps.setString(1, userName);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if a user provides a name like "anyu'; drop table users;", you could be for it.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you meant:

```
delete from users where name = 'auyu'
```

This is still a pretty odd SQL command to give to a "save" method.

I'd also *strongly* suggest that you use parameterised SQL statements instead of embedding data directly into the SQL itself - particularly if the data has come from the user.

Comment: Thanks what if I need to use a String like this:
String s = "auyu";

Comment: @Rocky: Use a preparedStatement (or string concatenation); see my answer for details on the PS option.

Answer (score 2):

You need single quotes around the auya ('auyu') and you'll need to escape them like so:

```
"delete from users where name = \'auyu\'"
```